# Passing empty value to DBReport mediator

Tags: wso2-esb

Is there a way to pass null parameter to sql query using DBReport mediator?
I get empty value for my soap property and WSO2 fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its is null use filter mediator to check the null and then use dbreport mediator.